# What's the name of the minimum number of transpositions required to build a permutation?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, permutations

What's the name of the minimum number of transpositions required to build a permutation? I thought it was "rank" but apparently "rank" refers to the lexicographic number.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose it could be called [length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_function).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a fixed terminology. [Here](http://rfgsemisimply.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/length-of-a-permutation/), that number is called the length of a permutation (and notice that it has a nice description in terms of the cycle-type).

I believe it is more standard for the length of a permutation to refer to the minimum number of transpositions *of adjacent entries* required to build a permutation. This is the same as the number of "inversions", i.e., if $\pi$ is your permutation, then the length is the number of pairs of indices $a<b$ with $\pi(a)>\pi(b)$, which is not invariant under conjugation.